# How can I delete multiple rows from a table with another condition?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I have a table like this:

```
Id  Name     ProductId

1   Apple    1
2   Apple    null
3   Apple    2
4   Orange   1
5   Orange   2
6   Pear     null
7   Lemon    1
8   Lemon    null
```

I want to delete a row if it's `ProductId is null` **and** if it's `Name` is occurs more than once.

At this example if I run a proper delete query, it should **delete** these rows:

```
2   Apple    null
8   Lemon    null
```

Which kind of delete query can work for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using aggregation or something similar before joining:

```
delete t from test t join
       (select t.name, count(*) as cnt
        from test t
        group by t.name
       ) tt
       on t.name = tt.name
where tt.cnt > 1 and t.product_id is null;
```

This is much better than a self join without aggregation.  Why?  Because each row is identified exactly once.  In your sample data, a self-join *without* aggregation attempts to delete row id = 2 twice (once for the match to 1 and once for the match to 3).  That is unnecessary.  And it can become highly inefficient if a `name` has many rows.

I also think that you don't simply want a cnt of 2 but you want a non-`NULL` product id.  That is:

```
delete t from test t join
       (select t.name, count(*) as cnt
        from test t
        where product_id is not null
        group by t.name
       ) tt
       on t.name = tt.name
where tt.cnt >= 1 and t.product_id is null;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=682162e9edcc743e54bf45143527c72d) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Does this code works? I thought the syntax only can be DELETE FROM tablename  ... I got syntax error, can you correct it please?

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3f61ae08b277d3c2890503a420321a1a

Comment: I can see, but I still got syntax error.
Can you test your code it here and fix it please?

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a4c2f3b1827828a41ffd901c6466fc99

Answer (score 2):

```
DELETE t
FROM test t
INNER JOIN test t2
   ON t.name = t2.name
WHERE
   t.product_id is null
   AND t2.id <> t.id
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e58dc760d30bfaec4e46be7c80729200

Comment: @BusinessMan . . . I am uncomfortable with this answer because the intermediate result will include rows to be deleted multiple times -- when `name` as more than two rows.

Comment: Thank you, it works well!
Now I know the key was the Cartesian product.
It works as well:


`DELETE t

FROM test t, test t2

WHERE

   t.name = t2.name
   AND
   t.product_id is null
   AND t2.id <> t.id`

Comment: @GordonLinoff, you are right, I haven't attached much importance to that, and it can be my mistake. This code will lead to some perfomance issue?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Unfortunately I don't know which has a better performance.
But your answer looks more effective if I have a much bigger table.